# Conflict between packages noindentafter and atbeginend

Tags: packages, noindentafter

The following MWE shows a conflict between the packages `noindentafter` and `atbeginend`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{
  atbeginend,
  noindentafter,
  %atbeginend, %<- Exchanging the loading order won't work
 }

\NoIndentAfterEnv{enumerate}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is not indented.

This is indented. Follows an enumeration:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enough.
\end{enumerate}

I am indented. Do not indent me.

\noindent I am not indented.
\end{document}
```

Instead of a specific hack to be input by the user, I think that an amedment to any of those packages would be the way to go.

Comment: Where can we find `atbeginend`?

Comment: Apparently it's this here: [atbeginend](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/atbeginend.sty) -- well `noindentafter` uses `etoolbox`, which has it's own mechanism of `\AtBeginEnvironment` etc, so this must conflict. I think you should not load `atbeginend` at all! You're not using it's feature in your MWE

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: That's the package indeed. Well, right, I'm not using it at all here except for showcasing the conflict. In my original setting I'm effectively using it.

Comment: I don't know whether it is worth to pursue this conflict. `atbeginend` is not available on CTAN, on TeXlive or Miktex -- it seems to be a 'shadow' package. I recommend to switch to `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment` from `etoolbox` which is a very good package!

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: You have a good point, but I've been using this small package in several of my own classes because it made some things easier for me than the hooks available from `etoolbox`. Anyway, it is not such a big deal for me not to use one or the other depending on the context; I just thought it might be useful to someone else learning of this conflict. If it is not an appropriate question for the site because `atbeginend` is not on CTAN I don't really mind that this post be closed.

Comment: Better than loading a package to fix the broken document, it would be better to fix the document. "I am indented. Do not indent me." is indented because the document has blank lines that specify a paragraph break and thus indentation. If that sentence is not a new paragraph the blank lines should not be there

Comment: @David Carlisle: I usually leave a blank line in the source text because it helps me in locating visually the environments, which to me is particularly helpful regarding displayed mathematical contents (`equation` and the like). Also, although I may be wrong here, depending on the environment, not leaving such a line can preclude `TeX` from having vertical glue at that point, and depending in turn on the context, having that glue may be useful in the final composition of the page.

Comment: sorry it is wrong to treat tex white space as cosmetic indentation in the source. a blank line is parsed as `\par` and denotes the end of a paragraph. latex display environments and for math and lists etc go to some effort to detect a blank line before or after the display and indent or not indent the following block of text just in case there is a paragraph  break.

Comment: vertical glue is added around lists (and display math) whether or not the display is mid-paragraph (and so has no following indentation) or at tehe end of a paragraph (when the following text is indented)

Comment: note leaving a blank line before display math is worse than leaving it before a list, tex always does the wrong thing in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blank line (before or after the list) denotes a paragraph break and that signals to latex to indent the following text as a new paragraph. if there is no blank line the list is considered as part of the existing paragraph and the following text is not indented.

So, if the document markup is corrected, no package is needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section*{zzz}
This is not  indented.

This is indented. Follows an enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enough.
\end{enumerate}
I am not indented. Do not indent me.

I am  indented.
\end{document}
```

Note that internally each item of the list and the list itself use separate paragraphs to control margins and vertical space, but latex (in the case of lists) or the tex engine itself (in the case of display math) adjusts the typesetting of the following "internal" paragraph if the display is to be considered as logically part of the surrounding paragraph, to suppress indentation and in some cases use tighter vertical spacing.

Comment: Although not properly an answer to my original question regarding the conflict between the packages, the comments are valuable enough to make it more interesting than an answer in the strict sense. I wonder if you could possibly expand it by adding the comments you made on my wrong assumption about glue. Btw, this just reminded me of Wittgenstein's "question dissolving" in that my real problem was actually my thinking that I had a genuine problem as stated in my post.